# How can you access net applications on wsl 2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, sftp, wireless-access-point

I need to send a file from one WSL to another for a task I'm given. I tried to use `scp` command, but it requires me to get a wifi0 IP address for the network both devices are connected to, which I don't have.

[image]

I looked online and apparently WSL is in its own virtual ethernet sub-network and can't exactly send files to another device via Wi-Fi, however the other device does show the wifi0 data when I use the `ifconfig` command. I am very confused about the difference between the two devices and how one WSL can access wifi while the other can't.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu on the WSL and if so what version?

Comment: *"send a file from one WSL to another"* -> Are the two WSL instances running on the same Windows machine or different systems?  It sounds like different systems from the rest of the answer.  Can both of the Ubuntu/WSL systems `ping 8.8.8.8` successfully?  If so, it seems they are both accessing WiFi.  If not, then we can start by troubleshooting that issue.  Please do include the output of `wsl -l -v` for all applicable installations.  Thanks!